# react useEffect fetch data is completed but returning a value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am using `useEffect` to fetch array data then display items. When I fetch data I could see that the data is fetched successfully.

But when I try to display data in the `view` it gives me an error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I think the `view` is rendering before the fetch. But I used `async await` to make sure the `useEffect` is called first.

Any idea of how to get the data display in the `view`?

Any comments or advice would be really helpful. Thanks in advance :)

```
const FetchUsers = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState([])
    const URL = "myurl..."

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await axios.get(URL, {headers: {"x-access-token":memberToken}});
            const response = await res;
            console.log(response.data.data,'data')
            //when I console log
            // [{…}, {…}] "data"
            //0: { name: "kevin", age: 39}
            //1: { name: "john", age: 23}
            console.log(response.data.data[0].title, 'name')
            setData(response.data.data);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])


  return(

    <View>
      //I am trying to display fetched data  
      <Text>{data[0].name}</Text>
    </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "called first". Your component renders immediately, `useEffect` contains a "side-effect" - something that happens at some unknown point after your component renders....

Because of this, `data` will be set at some point in the future, so you have to check if it's available first, if it's not, then render something in it's place, like:

```
return(
 <View>
  <Text>{!data.length ? 'Loading...' : data[0].name}</Text>
 </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect()` will only trigger once the component is finished rendering and when the `state` or `props` changes. In your case, you are displaying the `name` attribute at initial render. This is the lifecycle, render > useEffect > props/state change? > useEffect > render.

use this instead:

```
return (
    <View>
        <Text>{data.length > 0 ? data[0].name : 'Fetching...'}</Text>
    </View>
);
```